# Adding to the value an item in a list

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Dim rooster(29, 19) As Label
Dim snake As List(Of Label) = New List(Of Label)

snake.Add(rooster(14, 10))
```

Now let's say I'd want to make this item in the list rooster(15,10). How would I do it?

Comment: This answers your question as asked: `rooster(14, 10) = rooster(15, 10)`. But I'm guessing it's not that easy. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Label objects' uniquely identifiable data is stored in the Text attribute, then try something like this:

```
    For Each l As Label In snake
        If l.Text = rooster(14, 10).Text Then
            l.Text = rooster(15, 10).Text
        End If
    Next
```